# How do you properly punctuate a list of expresssions?

Tags: punctuation, lists

If I'm listing expressions in a sentence, do I put the proper punctuation for the sentence *as well as* a comma after the expression?

For example:

**Objectives**

To learn to use the expressions "Would you like to run?", "Yes, I would.", and "No, I wouldn't."

OR

**Objectives**

To learn to use the expressions "Would you like to run," "Yes, I would," and "No, I wouldn't."

---

Additionally, should there be any punctuation after the word "expressions"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no universal rule for that sort of situation; it is something that a style guide would typically address.  There would probably also be some differences in [American vs British](http://www.guardian.co.uk/media/mind-your-language/2011/may/19/mind-your-language-punctuation-quotations) styles.

Personally, I favor the first.  It keeps the original punctuation of the quote intact and seems clear enough.  I would add no punctuation after the word 'expressions'.

You might also consider rewording things using a bulleted list to avoid the issue.  For example:

> To learn to use the expressions:
>
> - "Would you like to run?"
> - "Yes, I would."
> - etc.

Answer (score 0):

A conventional way of listing items that contain their own punctuation is to separate those items by a semicolon rather than by a comma.  Your example text would appear as follows:

*To learn to use the expressions, "Would you like to run?"; "Yes, I would."; and "No, I wouldn't."*

And yes, there must be a comma after "expressions", since what follows offers details that clarify that plural noun.

The semicolons may feel unnatural but it is a common construct when dealing with awkward lists like yours.

Comment: I really think the semicolons look strange, I know you use semi colons when your list contains phrases without quotes, but with quotes it just looks strange. Can you cite a source for this?